# Barba js - Listen on data Attributes?

Tags: attributes, href, data-url

Is it possible to listen on an element with an attribute like data-url or data-href?

**Example:**

```
<div data-url="/another/path/"> ... </div>
<button data-url="/another/path/">Go</button>
```

[Here is the Barba library](https://github.com/luruke/barba.js)